# How to include node of a certain content type as links in a menu?

Tags: routes

I have create a menu called: **Products**. Then I have a content type called: **Product**. 
Now when I create a **Product** node I need it automatically include in the **Products** menu.

Then if I have 10 nodes I should have a menu with 10 links.

Should I use a Rule to accomplish this?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems like I have to create a View to include all **Product** nodes. But I don´t know how to create the menu item using this View.

Comment: Should I use this module to produce a menu from a view? http://drupal.org/project/menu_node_views

Comment: I just found a module to do it: http://drupal.org/project/nodehierarchy and here an screencast to learn how to use it: http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode45

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with Rules. This module: http://drupal.org/project/menu_rules adds some actions to rules. One of them is to create a menu item for a node. You select:
Event: Create a node | Update a node
Condition: Content type is "your content type"
Action: Update a menu item for node (there is a checkbox to create the menu item if it doesnt exist)